# Komma beim Bedingungssatz

Tags: comma, conjunction

Kann oder muss man vor der Konjunktion "wenn" ein Komma setzen[,] wenn diese nachgestellt ist?

> Dürft ihr die Wörterbücher nur benutzen[,] wenn jeder eins dabei hat?

Darf man hier überhaupt ein Komma setzen?

Answer (score 11):

Man **muss** ein Komma vor dem *wenn* setzen:

> Dürft ihr die Wörterbücher nur benutzen, wenn jeder eins dabei hat?

Aus den amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln ([PDF](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf)):

> § 74   Nebensätze grenzt man mit Komma ab; sind sie eingeschoben, so schließt man sie mit paarigem Komma ein.

Comment: Die deutsche Wikipedia bietet zum Begriff [Nebensatz](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebensatz) auch eine Liste mit Arten von Nebensätzen im Deutschen. Das könnte hilfreich sein, um sich typische Satzmuster mit Komma zu vergegenwärtigen.